# What does require('path'); means in Webpack.config.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I was configuring **webpack configuration** with my own instead of copy things and paste , I just need to understand each and every line in Webpack configuration file.

What is the use of the first line **require('path')** in webpack Configuration File.

```
const path = require('path');

 module.exports = {
     entry: './src/app.js',
     output: {
         path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bin'),
         filename: 'app.bundle.js'
     }
 };
```

https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html 
I am following the above link to **getting things started**

in the **module.exports** , path has been used but i did not get any idea in the usage of the path. Please let me know the usage. So i can start further.

Comment: I suppose it's [this](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`path` is Node.js native utility module.

https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

`require` is Node.js global function that allows you to extract contents from `module.exports` object inside some file.

Unlike regular NPM modules, you don't need to install it because it's already inside Node.js

In your example you use `path.resolve` method which creates proper string representing path to your file.

Straight from docs:

> The path.resolve() method resolves a sequence of paths or path
>   segments into an absolute path.

https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths